# Edit Policy: Helpful vs Readability

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40755866/getting-array-from-a-json-response), there is a JSON string which had the following erroneous tail.

```
{ temp = 304.15, pressure = 1007, humidity = 62, temp_min = 304.15, temp_max = 304.15 }
```

**Part 1:**

An accepted edit, by someone other than OP, prettified the string by removing the erroneous tail. There is absolutely no information in the edit about the erroneous portion.

I think, this can lead to answers that turn out to be not helpful for the OP. More sadly, this can also stop posting of *could be helpful* answers. I also think that the editor could have posted an answer about how to remove the erroneous tail, instead of the edit.

**Part 2:**

I could not find any *undo edit* option. So I attempted an edit by undoing previous accepted edit (and keeping erroneous tail). I also tried to explain my concern in "Edit summary". The edit had been rejected by 3-to-2. All 3 rejects says

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read,
>   easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either
>   completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

**Question/Discussion:**

1. What should be the primary focus of an edit (and/or edit-review)? Helping the user, bringing helpful answers? Or, (supposedly unhelpful) readability?
2. What could be undo-edit (and/or undo-edit-review) policy?

Comment: _"erroneous tail"_? What? Where?

Comment: @Cerbrus the extra JSON block at the end.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. I rolled back the edit and placed the extra block on a new line. We don't need 40 lines of data in a question.

Answer (score 23):

This is a fortunate example because it shows two basic Stack Overflow principles:

1. why you should **never** edit code in a question: because that might accidentally 'solve' the OP's problem
2. why you should **always** prettify your code and output before posting it here: because the solution to your problem might suddenly become obvious.

In this case, I feel that an edit prettifying the JSON would be acceptable, provided that it doesn't remove the tail. In any case, the question can be closed as the problem is caused by a simple 'typographical' error.

In these cases, please *rollback* the edit because it is harmful. If you have 2k reputation, you can do this from the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40755866/revisions). If you don't, you can edit the post in the normal way, but select a previous revision to start from and save it as a suggested edit. Please indicate in the edit summary that you intend to do a rollback of an edit that changed the code. It is unfortunate that you encountered [some reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14383043) who didn't pay attention - you did the right thing.

Comment: I did edit the post. Please see **Part 2**.

Comment: @sazzad, there is `edit` button on each revision. Anyway, I don't see applicable edit ways for original question. I mean ways that will be approved in review queue.

Comment: @sazzad *rollback* is how we call the undo-functionality. These kind of edits should be rolled back.

Comment: @Glorfindel, Thanks. I guess my lack of knowledge is because of my lack of reputation.

Comment: You'll get there, eventually. You display a better understanding of the site than a lot of people with 4 or 5 digit reputation.

Comment: "Never" is, [as I've said before](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320037/should-we-change-void-main-to-int-main-in-the-ops-code#comment328359_320046), a bit too strong: if I know enough to answer the question, then I generally know whether this bit of JSON is in fact the cause or if it's just an extraneity.